# at the age of XX years "old"

Tags: phrase-usage, time-words

> *Military conscription is required of all Israeli citizens between the ages of 18 and 25 years old.*

Is the usage of "between the ages of 18 and 25 years old" correct here? Is the word "old" acceptable or necessary here?

> Dad retired at the age of 56.

Can I say -"Dad retired at the age of 56 years *old*?"

Comment: Source please. I could not find that sentence. And yes, it's redundant. *Age, years, and old* don't go together. Or at least, it'll look strange!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds odd. I think the perfect way to phrase the sentence is to avoid **'old'**. It is an unwanted repetition of 'age'.

> *Military conscription is required of all Israeli citizens between the ages of 18 and 25 years*.

Additionally, even if you edit out *'years'*, the sentence will still be valid and meaningful.

> *Military conscription is required of all Israeli citizens between the ages of 18 and 25.*